# WPF Binding a List<T> to a ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, combobox

So I have this `Window` class:

```
public partial class WorkerCard : Window
{
    public string jobsPath;
    public List<Job> List { get; set; }

    public WorkerCard()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Worker w = new Worker
        {
            Num = 1,
            Id = 123456789,
            Name = "ישראל",
            Last = "ישראלי",
            City = "",
            WorkStart = new DateTime(2015, 10, 1),
            WorkEnd = new DateTime(2017, 1, 1),
            Job = new Job
            {
                Name = "",
                Rate = 0,
                Global = 0
            },
            Rides = 0,
            Ride = false
        };
        this.DataContext = w;

        string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + "\\ShalomCollege\\";
        Job[] jobs = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Job[]>(File.ReadAllText(path + "jobs.json"));
        List = jobs.OfType<Job>().ToList();
    }
}
```

I wanted to bind the `Worker` object to some `TextBox`es which I did, but then I needed to bind a `List` (or an array) of `Job` objects to a `ComboBox`. Nothing seems to work.

XAML (separated the `ComboBox`):

```
<Window x:Class="ShalomColl.WorkerCard"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ShalomColl"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="WorkerCard" Height="350" Width="350">
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="IsZero" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Job.Rate}" Value="0">
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid FlowDirection="RightToLeft">
    <StackPanel x:Name="stackPanel">
        <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
            <Label DockPanel.Dock="Left" Content="ת.ז:" />
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Id}" MaxLength="9" />
        </DockPanel>
        <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
            <Label DockPanel.Dock="Left" Content="שם פרטי:" />
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}" />
        </DockPanel>
        <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
            <Label DockPanel.Dock="Left" Content="שם משפחה:" />
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Last}" />
        </DockPanel>
        <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
            <Label DockPanel.Dock="Left" Content="תחילת עבודה:" />
            <DatePicker Text="{Binding WorkStart}" />
        </DockPanel>
        <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
            <Label DockPanel.Dock="Left" Content="סיום עבודה:" />
            <DatePicker Text="{Binding WorkEnd}" />
```

```
        <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
            <Label DockPanel.Dock="Left" Content="תפקיד:" />
            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding List}" />
        </DockPanel>
```

---

```
        <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
            <Label DockPanel.Dock="Left" Content="יישוב:" />
            <ComboBox x:Name="City" />
        </DockPanel>
        <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
            <Label DockPanel.Dock="Left" Content="תעריף לשעה:" />
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Job.Rate}" Style="{StaticResource IsZero}" />
        </DockPanel>
        <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
            <Label DockPanel.Dock="Left" Content="משכורת גלובאלית:" />
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Job.Global}" Style="{StaticResource IsZero}" />
        </DockPanel>
        <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
            <CheckBox x:Name="chkBox" VerticalAlignment="Center" DockPanel.Dock="Left" IsChecked="{Binding Ride}" />
            <Label DockPanel.Dock="Left" Content="נסיעות:" />
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Rides}" IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=chkBox, Path=IsChecked}" />
        </DockPanel>
    </StackPanel>
    <Button Content="שלח" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,0,0,20" Width="70" Click="Submit" />
</Grid>
```

- **EDIT:**
  Found some sort of solution but I still don't get how it works. I just transferred my `List` into the `Worker` object. I assume the problem is with the `DataContext` because I can set only one at a time (which is currently on `Worker`).
- Still looking for an answer though...

Comment: notify UI ? implement inotifypropertychanged or try using observablecollection and add items to it

Comment: @Muds Could you please post an answer that gives an example on how to do that and close to my situation?

Comment: @Muds ? (7 more to go...)

Comment: well I overlooked the fact that GazTheDestroyer has mentioned, you need to point to correct DataContext first ..

Answer (score 1):

You have set the `DataContext` of your view to an instance of `Worker`, but your `List` property is on the view.

You can use `RelativeSource` to point back the view for that one binding.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding List, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}" />
```

Or `ElementName` if you put a name on the window:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding List, ElementName=root" />
```

If you have problems with bindings then take a look in your DevStudio output window, as binding errors will show up there and will generally give you a clue as to what's going wrong.